# Using the dedicated graphics card on an external monitor

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, lenovo-laptop, external-display

I have just bought a Lenovo Yoga 730 15" with an Intel graphics card and a Geforce 1050 graphics card. It runs games perfectly fine when I'm using the internal monitor, but as soon as I change to an external monitor I'm getting much lower fps. I don't have any numbers, but it goes from smooth to not playable with the same settings.

Both monitors are 4K 60 Hz. I'm using Thunderbolt 3 with an HDMI-adapter (2.0, 4K 60 Hz) for the external monitor.

According to Windows, both the internal and the external monitor uses the Intel card. Since the games runs fine on the internal monitor I assume the physical connections goes through the Intel card even when the Geforce card is in use.

How do I force the Geforce card to be used on the external monitor?

(I'm not sure if this is the right forum for this question, point me to the correct one otherwise!)

Comment: Have you tried disabling the internal graphics card in UEFI? The setting could include something like IGP/IGPX or like this. Some manufacturers only include this option in their high-end gaming section.

Comment: It's only possible to disable the Geforce card in UEFI, I can switch between "Intel only" and "Switchable".
However, I've noticed that the Geforce card is in fact in use. If I check the task manager and run games, it's only the Geforce card thas is doing work, even if I chose to only use the Intel card in nVidia control panel. This makes my problem even more strange since the game should have the same fps when the same card is in use.